# isAllowed() is not taking the parameters value

Tags: zend-framework

```
    class Application_Plugin_AccessCheck extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract 
    {
        private $_auth=null;
        private $_acl=null;

        public function __construct() {

            $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
            $acl = new Zend_Acl;

            $this->_auth = $auth;
            $this->_acl = $acl;
        }


       public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
       {
           $resource = $request->getControllerName();



           $action = $request->getActionName();

           $identity = $this->_auth->getStorage()->read();
           $role = $identity->role;



         if(!$this->_acl->isAllowed($role,$resource,$action)){
               $request->setControllerName('Auth')
                       ->setActionName('login'); 
         }
           //echo '<pre>';print_r('inside plugins......success');die();

       }
    }




This is the ACL plugin page i am using. 

In this particular line
if(!$this->_acl->isAllowed($role,$resource,$action))

The function isAllowed is not taking the parameters, the url comes blank.
If i assign if(!$this->_acl->isAllowed($role=null,$resource=null,$action=null)), the page opens but it doesn't have any meaning if i set null. 
Seeking for Help

I am adding the model class "AsiaAcl.php" for more clearification


class Model_Asian_Acl extends Zend_Acl{
    public function __construct(){
        $this->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('data'));
        $this->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('updatecat'),'data');
        $this->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('detelecategory'),'data');

        $this->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('datas'));
        $this->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('listcat'),'datas');

        $this->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('user'));
        $this->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('admin'),'user');

        $this->allow('user','datas','listcat');
        $this->allow('admin','data','updatecat');
        $this->allow('admin','data','deletecategory');

    }
}



Thanks.
```

Comment: If you can, please clarify your question, I am understanding where your having problems. Plus, I don't see any roles, resources, or privileges being added to your ACL. Did you leave that out intentionally?

Comment: I created roles/resources in model named AsiaAcl.php . Should i have to include that model class too?

Comment: i edit the question, please see it again!! I really need help desperately :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I am not blind but your ACL is just an empty object. From what I see you have not assigned any roles and access control to the ACL.

With isAllowed() you check a role and resource but there is nothing the ACL has to check against. You have to either create/extend your own ACL class or you assign the roles and controls on the fly in your plugin.

See [ACL Doku](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.acl.introduction.html)

**Update**
Great, you have your own ACL class but you are not using it!

```
$acl = new Zend_Acl;
// this is just the empty default ACL, no roles nothing

// you should connect your own ACL class like this
$acl = new Model_Asian_Acl;
```

If haven't look at your ACL class closely but I think it should work.

Comment: Thx a lot Adrian. I changed the model name as Application_Model_AsiaAcl and connect a class as $acl = new Application_Model_AsiaAcl; And it works :D:D

I really appreciate your help for a zend beginner like me....keep smiling))

Comment: @Frozenfire Glad to help, I'll smile more if you check my answer and add an upvote.

Comment: Adrian i am new to stackoverflow...and i needs 15 reputation to upvote :( but it is true that your answer helps me to get solution ))

Comment: No problem. This forum has a rating system and if you don't participate you don't get points and with that you won't get much response in the future cause people see you ask a lot but don't respond.

Comment: ok....i'll try to respond other's questions too....thanks for the advice adrain!!!